# MYSQL: If/Else syntax

Tags: mysql

Working on a query but I need to implement some if else logic to check for a loop but I keep getting a 1064 bad syntax error.

I've gone over the manual and some examples  but still no luck. So I stripped down my query to the most basic comparison below:

```
SET @start_date = '2019-06-01';
SET @other_date = CURDATE();

IF @start_date < @other_date THEN 
Select 'True';
ELSE
Select 'False';
END IF;
```

The below is the read out I receive from status:

> SET @start_date = '2019-06-01'
>   OK
>   Time: 0.065s

SET @other_date = CURDATE()

> OK
>   Time: 0.065s

IF @start_date < @other_date THEN 
Select 'True'

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @start_date < @other_date THEN 
>   Select 'True'' at line 1
>   Time: 0.067s

I understand that  I'm going wrong somewhere with my syntax on the IF clause but in the docs it states:

IF [condition] THEN
if-statements
ELSE
   else-statements;
END IF;

I'm not sure why this is failing, any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For queries there is no `IF...ELSE...` statement (which you can use in stored procedures/functions).
Instead you can use the function [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT IF(@start_date < @other_date, 'True', 'False');
```

or the [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @start_date < @other_date THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jwLuMxiRSJv9XaU63peZWK/0).

Comment: What about for Loops? The whole reason I started looking at this and got stuck was because  this logic is the control factor for a loop for a custom report. If stored procs and functions have different if/else syntax. Which is appropriate for a loop? This is what I had. `WHILE (@start_date < NOW() &&  SUBDATE(@start_date, INTERVAL -2 WEEK) < NOW()) DO ...`

Comment: You don't normally use loops in queries. In stored procedures/functions of course you can. If what you want is to write a stored procedure then you can use loops and if statements as well.

Comment: @nbk What does this have to do with `RANK`?

Comment: i shoud you an example with a loop where you use a if clause, i thought you meant that with your question about ifs and loops

Comment: @nbk this is not a loop (if this is what you implied).

Answer (score 1):

You  syntax is false

```
SET @start_date = '2019-06-01';
SET @other_date = CURDATE();

SELECT 
IF (@start_date < @other_date, 'True','False');
```

The result is true